# MySQL Connector is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, mysql-connector

I have downloaded and installed MySql Connector for .NET **6.10.7**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="assemblies" type="Simple.Framework.AssembliesConfigurationSection, Simple.Framework"/>
  </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>      
        <add name="PTSystemMySql"
            connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Database=PrescriptionTrackingSystem;User ID=root;Password=xyz;"
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But, I have two problems:

1. `MySql.Data.dll` isn't showing up in the Visual Studio reference manager:

[image]

2. I have manually added `MySql.Data.dll`:

[image]

But, I am still getting an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' 
occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework 
Data Provider.`
```

**Note.** I am 100% sure that there is no problem with the source code. Coz, the source code is fully functional in case of MS Access and MS SQL Server.

Comment: Did you try to install the MySQL Connector from nugget package manager? In this [page](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/MySQL/) you can see all the connectors, there are available at the nugget package manager. If you install it with nugget, they automatic will be added to your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use an old version of .NET (your screenshot shown "Targeting: .NET Framework 2.0").

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html), connector version 6.10.7 required .Net 4.5.2 at least.

Comment: Do you not agree with this answer? Do you need more information?

Comment: I agree this is most likely the issue.